# qMetaTypeID doesn't evaluate to constant expression?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, compile-time, constant-expression

I'm trying to get the ID of a `QMetaType` at compile time, however when I try this very simple base case:

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(helloqt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(helloqt Qt5::Widgets)
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
struct Test{

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (Test)
constexpr int test_enum = qMetaTypeId<Test>();
int main() {
    qDebug() << test_enum;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:54:0,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:46,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:44,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from ...\main.cpp:1:
...\main.cpp:8:51:   in constexpr expansion of 'qMetaTypeId<Test>()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1754:43: error: 'static constexpr int QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id() [with T = Test]' called in a constant expression
     return QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id();
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1618:40: note: 'static constexpr int QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id() [with T = Test]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
     static inline Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1618:96: error: call to non-constexpr function 'static int QMetaTypeId<Test>::qt_metatype_id()'
     static inline Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }
                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\helloqt.dir\build.make:63: CMakeFiles/helloqt.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/helloqt.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/helloqt.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: helloqt] Error 2
```

It seems to imply qMetaTypeID is not a constant expression, yet this is what I see in my editor.

[image]

and this code compiles fine:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int x = 3;
int main() {
    static_assert(x == 3);
    return 0;
}
```

(I've tested with out using constexpr, and it doesn't work, which is as expected).

My compiler is Mingw-64, with QT version 5.10.1.

Comment: Does it work if you `#include "main.moc"` at the end of `main.cpp`?

Comment: @dtech Nope same exact error. I did need to make sure the meta object compiler was actually used though, so I had to edit the cmake file.  I get the following warning before hand though: `[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target helloqt
AutoMoc warning:
  ".../main.cpp"
The file includes the moc file "main.moc", but does not contain a Q_OBJECT, Q_GADGET or Q_NAMESPACE macro.

[ 25%] Built target helloqt_autogen`

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple: The metatype id is not designed to be a constant expression **in general**. For anything but some basic types, the values assigned will vary - they are assigned at runtime and depend on relative timing of the use of individual Qt modules, changes in Qt modules, changes in your code, etc. Your design must not assume that those are constant values, or even same between runs, never mind between machines.

The id code assigns them at runtime, in a thread-safe manner.

#### TL;DR

- If you have to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` **yourself**, the id is **not** `constexpr`.
- The id **is** `constexpr` in the special case of Qt built-in types **only**.

#### Can it be Done for a Custom Type?

If you really need the `qMetatypeId<Type>()` to be constexpr, you have to take the responsibility for making it so by specializing `struct QMetaTypeId<Type>` (or `QMetaTypeId2`). And you have to ensure that the dynamically registered type (because yes, a dynamic registration is necessary for Qt to capture the helper functions for the type) is same as the statically assigned one.

There's no way to have Qt attempt a registration at a given id "hint". It'd be nice, but there's no way currently to do it (that I know of, that wouldn't require using private headers etc.).

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/static-metatype-50703377
#include <QtCore>

// Interface

#if defined(QT_WIDGETS_LIB) && defined(Q_OS_MAC)
constexpr int StaticMetatypeId = QMetaType::User + 1;
#else
constexpr int StaticMetatypeId = QMetaType::User + 0;
#endif

#define MY_DECLARE_STATIC_METATYPE(TYPE, METATYPEID) \
   MY_DECLARE_STATIC_METATYPE_IMPL(TYPE, METATYPEID)

#define MY_DECLARE_STATIC_METATYPE_IMPL(TYPE, METATYPEID) \
    QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE \
    template<> struct QMetaTypeId2<TYPE> \
    { \
        enum { Defined = 1, IsBuiltIn = false, MetaType = METATYPEID };   \
        static inline constexpr int qt_metatype_id() { return METATYPEID; } \
        static inline constexpr const char *static_name() { return #TYPE; } \
    }; \
    QT_END_NAMESPACE

template <typename T>
int registerStaticMetaType() {
   auto id = qRegisterMetaType<T>(QMetaTypeId2<T>::static_name(),
                                  reinterpret_cast<T*>(quintptr(-1)));
   Q_ASSERT(id == qMetaTypeId<T>());
   return id;
}

// Use

struct Foo {};
MY_DECLARE_STATIC_METATYPE(Foo, StaticMetatypeId + 0)

int main() {
   registerStaticMetaType<Foo>(); // StaticMetatypeId + 0
                                  // other registrations must follow in ascending order
   static_assert(qMetaTypeId<Foo>() == StaticMetatypeId+0, "try again :(");
}
```

Comment: 'What gave you the idea that those are constant expressions?' http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qMetaTypeId  The documentation?  And look at the error out put, clearly all those things are declared as constant expressions...

Comment: Have you looked at the code? You misunderstand what they mean by "compile time". What is meant is that given a compile-time type `T`, you can get its metatype id *at runtime* in general.

Comment: Yep I looked at the code, its confusing and there's way too much indirection, but everything is declared with constexpr. Its in QMetatype.h https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtCore/qmetatype.h.html#_Z11qMetaTypeIdv  Don't know if that is the same version but it looks similar enough to the open declaration I have.

Comment: "Returns the meta type id of type T at compile time"  Theres nothing to misunderstand here, returns the meta type ID of T at compile time, errors if Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is not used first, there is no implicit or explicit mention that this shouldn't work with user defined types.  The fact that it mentions Q_DECLARE_METATYPE needs to done first actually implies that it is supposed to work for user defined types

Comment: I've made it more clear. `qMetatypeId` is **in general not** constexpr -- recall that the `constexpr` keyword doesn't guarantee anything. It's not, because **not all of its implementations are**. It is `constexpr` in special cases - you need to look at how it's implemented for your type, not for Qt types.

Comment: Look, I don't know how else to explain it to you, but your observed behavior matches the code (hint: the non-constexpr implementation is in the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro). The documentation is perhaps misleading. What is really meant that as long as `T` is a Qt type (and I'm not sure if it's even all of Qt types), then it will be `constexpr`. Otherwise - not. The "compile time" refers to `T` being a compile-type typename. You may argue that the documentation says something it shouldn't - it's a documentation bug then, feel free to open a bug and submit a fix, it should go in no problem.

Comment: what do you mean implement it myself? I'm not going to know what number the MOC decided to compile my ID to before my actual program build for my custom object am I?  I need to use the ID in a switch statement which requires it to be constant expression.

Comment: @snb moc plays no role here. Moc only deals with `QObject` implementations, and you can't register metatypes for those because they are not values. `qMetaTypeId` system is for *values*, and `QObject`s make for poor values - they are neither copyable nor moveable and the metatype system can't handle such poor values yet. I've updated the answer to show how you can do what you want. **If you take care**. At least there's an assert that won't let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: I couldn't get your example to compile, until I switched the `+ 1` to `+ 0` in that `ifndef QT_WIDGETS_LIB` statement.  it failed on the Q_ASSERT.

Comment: @snb It is somewhat platform dependent perhaps. Or Qt version dependent. What's your version? But that's why the assert is there: otherwise, you'd get all sorts of interesting failures as type `Foo` would be destructed by type `Bar`'s destructor, and so on. Wonderful instanity, in other words.

Comment: I state my version in my post.  Qt5.10.1

Comment: Your macos thing fixed it, also why make impl macro?  Can't you directly use the macro?

Comment: @snb That's the [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) idiom. It's necessary to expand the arguments, should they be macros. I highly suggest that you do your own homework on this, don't just take a random SO answer without understanding of what's exactly going on (unless it's for a toy project). I have an inkling that you're using `qMetaTypeId` incorrectly anyway. Why do you use it? What for? It's low-level library implementation-level stuff, if you go that deep you must understand all of it well.

Comment: there's no entry point to "doing my own homework" on interacting with QT this way, feel free to provide a vector for that kind of information.  I'm using qMetaTypeId in a swtich case based on the type of a QVariant to transfer to another variant like structure which is used for serialization.  The other structure is from another library that has utilities QT doesn't provide, and ideally allows the program to run without QT dependencies when it needs to, so it can't be removed.

Comment: @snb The vector is: source. Alas, there are probably other ways of doing that conversion that don't involve writing switches by hand, but the obvious solution is: cache the metatype id in a const somewhere, and use `if` statements for the dynamic metatype ids. That's the only portable, non-hacky solution - don't fight the system, so to speak. You could register converters for various types to the other "variant" type, and then you could do `myVariant.value<OtherCoolType>()` and it would do the magic for you :)